# Cordova InAppPurchase: .getProducts() returns empty array

Tags: ios, cordova, in-app-purchase

I've been using [cordova-plugin-inapppurchase](https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-plugin-inapppurchase) in an Ionic app and it seems to execute without error, but it returns an empty array every time.

I have created a test product for a new (unreleased, of course) version of my app. It is in the "Ready to Submit" status.

In iTunes Connect, I have Bundle ID:

> com.testing.testingapp

In Xcode, the Bundle Identifier and Version default to something different (a much earlier mistake) but I overwrite it with the following, which it accepts and allows me to build:

> com.testing.testingapp
>
> 2.0 *(the version that has the Product)*

My code in the controller:

```
  console.log('about to try inAppPurchase.getProducts()');
  inAppPurchase
    .getProducts(['com.testing.testingapp.50_tokens']) // Product ID
    .then(function (products) {
      console.log("----------------------------");
      console.log(products);
      console.log("----------------------------");
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      console.log("----------------------------");
      console.log(err);
      console.log("----------------------------");
    });
```

What I see in the console once I hit a route that invokes that controller:

```
[Log] about to try inAppPurchase.getProducts() 
[Log] ----------------------------  
[Log] [] (0)  
[Log] ----------------------------
```

It seems to be executing just fine but doesn't return the product (`50_tokens`) that is in the "Ready to Submit" status for the version I'm testing.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: @LombaX  I did - the Product ID did not match the ID I had created in iTunesConnect. I had assumed the full path including 'com.testing' was implicit through a misreading of the documentation.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this is not the problem for me. I think that I must complete the bank and taxing part, I'm waiting for my customer to fill it.

Comment: @LombaX Did you figure this out ? my product ID is fine but I get an empty array :'(

Comment: @zahabba I don't understand u said in the comment to LombaX that u didn't put the 'com.testing' and that's why it wasn't working. But when I look at your snippet I see the com.testing.testingapp.50_tokens so I'm guessing that maybe I did not understand your answer to LombaX.

Comment: @Su4p I just had to make sure the product IDs matched. In iTunesConnect, the ID was something like `testingapp.50_tokens` and not the full `com.testing.testingapp.50_tokens` as I had used in my code above. They must be identical.

Comment: @zahabba on itunes connect my productID is "one_clinical_case" this product is part on an app com.mycompany.testapp. Should I put [ "one_clinical_case" ] in the getProducts ?

Comment: @zahabba  NB : My app is not available on the market, it's on testflight.

Comment: @Su4p , yes, in my case after my customer completed the bank and taxing section, it started working correctly

Comment: @LombaX thank you it's working now that I fulfiled my tax bank inquiries etc... on itunes connect.